# Can we do better with question closures?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/269021/rekey-smart-lock-for-2-keys) got closed inside of 3 hours.

I get that it was grossly underspecified, and I get the frustration with abandoned questions, but are we educating new users enough? Can we include a note that says something to the effect of, “if you revise this question with sufficient detail, it can be re-opened”? (I know there’s verbiage that suggests editing, but the re-open might be non-obvious to new users.)

Comment: Should new users be required to read all the help files BEFORE having access to posting capability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is a fundamental problem with a lot of terminology in StackExchange, not limited in any to DIY SE. In the case of "Close", I suspect to a lot of new users (and I think it took me quite a while to understand it myself, years ago), "Close" sounds an awful lot like "Delete". Yes, if you "Close" a door you can "Open" it again. But in a lot of other contexts, "Close" is a term that is rather "final".

Better wording might be "On Hold" or "Temporarily Closed". Yes, more explanation in the blue close box would help, but I suspect a lot of new users can't really get past the "[closed]" in the title line or the bold **Closed** in the blue box.

Comment: Been thinking this myself. "Closed" sounds permanent. "On Hold" is more temporary and sounds fixable. "Paused" might sound temporary and fixable too.